# I'm trying to create a procedure in Pl/Sql and I'm getting this error

Tags: oracle, plsql

https://i.stack.imgur.com/M4oUC.jpg - Picture

I'm trying to calculate the current product stock.
I have product_reception table in which I can calculate my stock. 
And sales (vanzari) table.

Comment: Please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors and update your question accordingly.

Comment: You are confusing pl/sql with sqlplus.

Answer (score 2):

Posting code as an image is usually a bad idea.

Anyway: quite a few objections:

- don't enclose procedure (or table, column, ...) name into double quotes
- name parameters so that their name is different from column names, for example: not `cod_pds in number` but `par_cod_pds in number`
- declare variable in the *declaration section*, which is between `is` and `begin`. Don't use `var` (key)word. It is a good idea to name them so that the name reflects the fact that these are *local variables*, such as `l_stoc_pds number`
- don't use `exec` within a PL/SQL procedure, especially not to run a `select` statement. `exec` is used in SQL*Plus to run a PL/SQL procedure, such as `exec calculstoclazi`
- don't `select into` a variable preceded by a colon, but simply name the variable
- those two `select` statements are exactly the same; I have no idea what you meant to do by doing that. Besides, you preceded `cod_pds` with `stoc_pds` which  is a variable name (so that's totally wrong); if a column name is to be preceded by something, that's table name (or its alias)

Therefore, code that *might* look like something valid is this; obviously, the result will be 0 (zero). As I told you, those two `selects` are exactly the same.

```
create or replace procedure calculstoclazi
  (par_cod_pds  in  number,
   par_rezultat out number
  )
is
  l_stocs_pds     number;
  l_total_vanzare number;
begin
  select sum(cantitate) 
    into l_stoc_pds
    from receptie_marfa
    where cod_pds = par_cod_pds;

  select sum(cantitate) 
    into l_total_vanzare
    from receptie_marfa
    where cod_pds = par_cod_pds;

  par_rezultat := l_stoc_pds - l_total_vanzare;
end;
```